# How I can upload a App from Sharepoint Framework?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying to upload a app generate with SharePoint Framework to the App Catalog of my SharePoint, but when I upload it, it don't recognize how a valid package and I can't add this app to my developer site where I upload the workbench. I don't see the app in the list of available apps for add.

I tried do all of the SharePoint framework guide but I don't accomplish upload a valid app.

[image]

Too, I tried to upload here the workbench but it don't work.

I hope your help for can deploy the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have to try to do things again. In the [guide](http://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page), you should

> Open package-solution.json from the config folder. The
>   package-solution.json file defines the package metadata as shown in
>   the following code:

```
{
    "solution": {
    "name": "helloworld-webpart-client-side-solution",
    "id": "ed83e452-2286-4ea0-8f98-c79d257acea5",
    "version": "1.0.0.0"
    },
    "paths": {
    "zippedPackage": "helloworld-webpart.spapp"
    }
}
```

When this is done, run the gulp command

```
gulp package-solution
```

> The command will create the package in the sharepoint folder:
>   helloworld-webpart.spapp

So far so good, next

> Upload or drag and drop the helloworld-webpart.spapp to the App
>   Catalog.

... and click Deploy.

When I do this, I get a ProductID on my dev-tenant App site, but from your screenshot I can tell that there is no ProductID, and maybe that's where things fail?

[image]

Another option, which you might have missed, is to install Drop 4 and upgrade your web parts? I had these issues doing a demo, and later on when I upgraded to Drop 4, everything worked like a charm. See [Release Notes Drop 4 and MDL2](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes-Drop-4-and-MDL2) on how to upgrade your apps.

Comment: I try to do all guide against and it works perfectly in local enviroment, but when i go to upload to the App Catalog it don´t recognise how a valid package. My main problem is when i upload it, i dont have the message to deploy it. I have admin permission for 365 site. I dont know why it dont work.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using a Developer Tenant, not a developer site.

Comment: But, if i want to use the app to a exist project of office 365 with my account of it? I can´t include the app build in it?

Comment: For now it only works on a Developer Tenant, use on other tenants will come later.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution name might be too long (in "package-solution.json"), the limit is 64 characters. Keep it <= 64 characters.

[image]

I had a similar problem [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211412/sharepoint-framework-web-parts-do-you-need-a-developer-tenant).