# SharePoint Framework web parts - do you need a developer tenant?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, spfx-webparts

I want to test my SharePoint Framework web part in Office 365, in SharePoint Online.

Therefore I upload the .sppkg file to the App Catalog. Unfortunately SharePoint says my app package is invalid:

[image: App package is not valid]

[Here is a similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195969/how-i-can-upload-a-app-from-sharepoint-framework) about invalid app packages where the answers say you need a developer tenant for it to work.

But what is a developer tenant? Is there a formal documentation describing the differences of a developer tenant compared to a "normal" one? I thought a dev tenant is just a "normal" one with first release features activated and maybe a pre-created developer site. Am I mistaken?

**=== ADDITION ===**

If there is a developer tenant subscription available I am more than willing to buy one. It just mustn't expire after x month. I need it to be like a normal tenant. Any hints on how to get such a tenant (and a comparison to "normal" tenants) are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: **no, you don't need a developer tenant**.

The reason the column "Valid App Package" was "No" is... my solution name is too long! **Apparently the solution name has a limit of 64 characters.** (Are you kidding me?)

Let's have a look.

That's ok and shown as valid package:

```
"name": "X012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012"
```

[image]
[image]

That's **not** and is shown as invalid package:

```
"name": "X0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123",
```

[image]
[image]

Note that the title (and other data) is not even displayed.

Well. Mystery solved.

Answer (score 2):

The SharePoint Framework reached general availability about a month ago so all tenants should support it by now. You might want to contact support.

[SharePoint Framework reaches general availability—build and deploy engaging web parts today](https://blogs.office.com/2017/02/23/sharepoint-framework-reaches-general-availability-build-and-deploy-engaging-web-parts-today/)

Comment: I think I will do this. Does not work in normal and dev tenant.

Answer (score 1):

this is called Office 365 developer subscription, it is different than the regular subscription.

You can sign up for the [Office Developer Program](https://profile.microsoft.com/RegSysProfileCenter/wizardnp.aspx?wizid=7a6e3d71-b057-49cc-b2aa-158ff23432f3&lcid=1033&culture=en-us&dir=LTR). make sure you sign out from the existing office 365 tenant ( if you are).

[Set up your Office 365 tenant](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/set-up-your-developer-tenant)

Comment: This is a good answer. You don't need a developer tenant if your tenant has what you need. However, it doesn't hurt to get one if you can.

Comment: But SharePoint Framework reached GA status - this should've been rolled out to all (first release?) tenants by now, right? (And developer tenants seem to always be "trial" tenants. I don't want to have a trial tenant. So for future developments it would be good to learn where to get a "durable" developer tenant. I don't find an option to buy one of those.)

Answer (score 1):

This error is getting if SPFx changes not been rolled out to a tenant. To confirm can you go to any site -> Site contents -> + New dropdown, you should see the "Page" option.

If you can able to see this option I can share sample package to check there are no issues in yours.

Developer tenant can be used to develop apps and test. This tenant comes with site collection created with developer template which is a mandatory to test Add-ins and SPFx frameworks. This you can register for a year free or you pay for a yearly subscription.

Thanks, 
Venkat Konjeti